# Connection With MySQL With Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am using this tutorial for connecting mysql database with android apps
[androidhive.info/2013/12/…](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/)

There are 4 files for PHP . They are Config.php , DbConnect.php , get_categories.php , new_category.php . After putting this  `http://localhost/food_api/get_categories.php`  to my browser , I get the following result .

```
{"categories":[{"id":"1","name":"Beverages"},{"id":"2","name":"Bread"},{"id":"3","name":"Cereals"},{"id":"4","name":"Cheese"},{"id":"5","name":"Citrus Fruits"}]}
```

But in my android application , there is no data coming from server . Where is the problem ? My assumption is that therre may be some mistake in url which is as following :

```
**// API urls
// Url to create new category
private String URL_NEW_CATEGORY = "http://10.0.2.2/food_api/new_category.php";
// Url to get all categories
private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://10.0.2.2/food_api/get_categories.php";**
```

My error is as following :

[image]

I am passing almost 2 days to solve this probelm , but could not get any solution . Please help me to solve this problem .

Comment: Your URLs don't seem to be accessible from the Internet.

Comment: I am working in my localhost server .

Comment: Yes you do, that's why the localhost link works just fine. The problem is that the external referenced one, via IP, is not accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the link- "10.0.2.2 " for localhost will work **only for emulator**.
If you try to work with real device this link will not work. In that case you have to host the php and database **in a global server** or you have to **make a lan/wlan with the mobile device** and then the pc **localhost url wil be the ip address of that PC**